# JavaScript printing wrong number with like 20 decimals

Tags: javascript, html

So this is my code:

```
requestList.push(newDrink("Beer 1", 1.2, "Quantity:33cl", 0, "Beer"));
```

"1.2" is the price. And there's another variable that is initialized with 1 which is the "quantity".

```
function printtolist()
{
   var price = requestList[i].price * requestList[i].quantity;

   alert(price);
}
```

So, pretty easy, and when i add more quantity i print it, so in this case the output should be like this.

```
 1.2   
 2.4
 3.6
 4.8
 6
 7.2
```

But i'm getting this:

```
1.2
2.4
3.599999999999996
4.8
6
7.199999999999999
```

And I can't understand this. Quantity is added with

```
requestList[i].quantity++
```

So my variables are like "doubles and ints". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with floating point arithmetic. Javascript cannot handle exact numbers. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken) for more details. However, since it appears that you're only using one decimal place, you can do this:

```
num=Math.round(num*10)/10;
```

Or as iccthedral pointed out in the comments, you can do this:

```
num.toFixed(1);
```

If you aren't going to do this, you shouldn't check if two numbers are equal with `==`, but rather you should check it with this:

```
if(Math.abs(num1-num1)<=1e-6){
    alert("They are equal!");
}
```

Comment: Used the math.round, thanks, now its fine.